# Check if the entire String value in Textbox is zero(0) or of special characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

I have a Textbox in which i'm getting the input of type text having the length 20, I have a scenario in which i have to evaluate whether the entire string input from the client is not zero or any special characters

e.g: `00000000000,00000,00,00000,00000/-/--,/-/-----////,aBadf-018---///sdf484,AA///---000`
all these above inputs are invalid, the string could be of any length in between 2 to 20,

i have restricted the user to input other special characters other than hyphen and dash, 
regex used over here to invalidate the value other than hyphen and dash are as follows :

`" /[^a-zA-Z0-9/-]/g "`

```
<input type="text" name="consumer_number" maxlength="25" ng-disabled="!form_data[selectedTab].electrici‌​ty.check" alpha-numeric-with-slash-and-hyphen data-ng-model="form_data[selectedTab].electric‌​ity.unique_no" class="input-field" data-ng-blur="validateElecConsumer(selectedTab‌​)" ng-class="{true:'invalid-field',false:''}[form‌​_data[selectedTab].e‌​lectricity.check && form_data[selectedTab].invalid.electricity]" required />
```

Now my concern is how could i display a message right upfront that whatever the input the user have provided is invalid.

Comment: Can you share code on what you have tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried using [ng-pattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) ?

Comment: You can setup a boolean/flag. So when you hit a invalid case set it to false. 
for example : $scope.isValid = false.
And you can use ng-if on that $scope.isValid in html to display what ever u want 
Anyway.. do share the code what u have till now so that we can help you more

Comment: @LL sorry for this unformmated code but this is what i have best possible option.
you can refer this plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/lSVuhUIA7dOwOd0puhqO?p=catalogue|

no i'm not using ng-pattern, despite i have written my own directive.

Comment: set your input ng-model="someValue" and your ng-pattern in the input and your validation message to <div ng-show="someValue.$error.pattern" right> Input text incorrect </div> right below. wrap both input and div msg in a closed div for a cleaner look so `<div><input maxlength="20" type="text" ng-model="someValue" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*$/" ng-reguired="true"/><div ng-show="someValue.$error.pattern"> Input is incorrect</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MyController", function($scope){
  $scope.inputtext = "";
  $scope.onSubmit = function() {
    var val = $scope.inputtext;
    if (val.length < 2 
        || val.length > 20 
        || !val.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9/-]/g)) {
      alert("Unacceptable");
    } else {
      alert("you pass");
    }
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController">
  <input  maxlength="20" 
      id="inputtext" 
      ng-model="inputtext" type="text"/>
  <button id="submitbutton" ng-click="onSubmit()" type="text">submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: this works, but only validates on click of the submit, if you want on fly you can do one of two things ng-focus with the function call onSubmit() or you can apply a div with error message that has ng-show="inputtext.$error.pattern" based on ng-pattern from the input field

Comment: @DrMints can you just help me out with that one as well, anything like plunker or jsfiddle. awaiting for your response, actually now the requirement has changed , message should prompt while typing only not on any click event. Thanks well in advance